# Passing default values in powershell to another script

Tags: powershell

Given:

**setenv.ps1**:

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][ValidateSet(541,642,643,644,645,"tmp")]$version=645)

echo "[setenv] Version = $version"
```

**dbupdate.ps1**:

```
param($version)

. setenv $version

echo "[dbupdate] Version = $version"
```

Output:

```
PS C:\> dbupdate.ps1
c:\utils\setenv.ps1 : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'version'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not
contain any null values and then try the command again.
At c:\utils\dbupdate.ps1:3 char:10
+ . setenv $version
+          ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [setenv.ps1], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,setenv.ps1

[dbupdate] Version =
```

I want to invoke `dbupdate.ps1` without any arguments, which should tell `setenv.ps1` use the default value for the `$version` argument. However, the default value is the implementation detail of the `serenv.ps1` script - I do not want it to "leak" into the `dbupdate.ps1`.

How do I do it?

**EDIT**

Trying to follow the advice of Cookie Monster yields the following error:

```
c:\dayforce\utils\setenv.ps1 : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'version'. The argument "System.Collections.Hashtable" 
does not belong to the set "541,642,643,644,645,tmp" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the 
set and then try the command again.
At C:\dayforce\utils\dbupdate.ps1:9 char:10
+ . setenv $params
+          ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [setenv.ps1], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,setenv.ps1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good use case for splatting your arguments.  Particularly if you ever need to do it for more than a single parameter...

Modified dbupdate.ps1:

```
param($version)

#Build a hashtable containing the parameters and values you want to call
$params = @{}
if($version) { $params.version = $version }

. setenv @params
```

You could even use @PSBoundParameters, there's an example of this in the help system.  Run Get-Help about_Splatting for more information!

**Edit for clarification**

Not sure why this was downvoted.  Here is verification that this syntax works.  Calling @params is required, not $params.

[image]

Lastly, here is one more example demonstrating splatting PSBoundParameters, even less code:

[image]

Get-Help about_Splatting or Googling "PowerShell splatting" will provide more examples if needed!

Comment: Is `@params` valid syntax?

Comment: This doesn't work, `an empty @{}` has the same problem with validateset.

Comment: Oops, my edit seems to be lost. SO has some problems.

Comment: Mark - @params is required.  Run Get-Help about_Splatting for more information.  I just verified that this exact scenario works.  Andy, an empty hash table splatted against a command does nothing, because no parameters match up.  If you use $params, PowerShell thinks you are passing $params in as the value for $version, rather than using splatting.  

`.\dbupdate.ps1 ...
[setenv] Version = 645`

Comment: I have just checked it with the `@` sign and it works as you describe. Cool, did not know about it. Whoever has downvoted you should upvote you back.

Answer (score 0):

Your overriding the default value with a value of null. The validateset attribute seems to be causing that error. I tried adding allownull,allowemptystring and allowemptycollection and added a null value to the set but validateset still caused that error. As an alternative you could just do this -

```
if ($version) {
   . .\setenv.ps1 $version
} else {
   . .\setenv.ps1
}
```